# FDT Max: "An internal error occured"

Tags: fdt

My FDT Max suddenly stop working. Everytime I start FDT, it shows an error message: "Showing FDT Welcome Screen has encounter a problem - An internal error occured" and after that I can't open any project or show any view. Please help

I've try to reinstalled a fresh copy and it's still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Write a bug report with log files attached and a short description of your environment to:
http://bugs.powerflasher.com